# laravel TokenMismatchException when trying to use disqus api

Tags: jquery, session, laravel, token

I am trying to send notifications to authors  when someone posts a comment to blog posts in disqus comment threads. In laravel I tried to filter both csrf tokens and csrf token of ajax calls in filters.php :

```
Route::filter('csrf_header', function()
{
  if (Session::token() != Request::header('x-csrf-token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;//line 126
    }
});
```

When I post a comment, I am getting:

```
{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Session\\TokenMismatchException","message":"","file":"\/home\/ytsejam\/public\/sirtcantalilar.com\/app\/filters.php","line":126}}
```

I try to post my comments as below :
in view-post.blade.php I added

```
<meta name="token" content="{{ Session::token() }}">
<script type="text/javascript">

     var disqus_config = function() {

      this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function(comment) {
        $.ajax({
                url: '/sendnotification',
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {
                         'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                         },
                data: { comment: comment.id, post:{{$post->id}}",author:"$post->author->id"},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                beforeSend: function(request) {
                           return request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='token']").attr('content'));
                   },
                success: function(ev) {

                         },
                error: function(xhr, error, status) {

                    }
             });


         }];
     };
</script>
```

Can you help me to solve this problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kdocki/3259dc0d06b212102004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time , as noone answered my question, you can solve this problem with the gist in the comment and other option is using jquery :

```
$(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
});
 var disqus_config = function() {

    this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function(comment) {
            $.ajax({
                        url: '/sendnotification',

                          type: 'POST',
                          data: { comment: comment.id, post: "{{$post->id}}",author:"{{$author->id}}"},
                          dataType: 'JSON',
                         async: true,
                         success: function(data){
                            process(data)
                         }
                });


    }];
};
```

and adding csrf token in the head section :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<?= csrf_token() ?>">
```